# Value con varios datos como cacharlo en otras paginas en PHP

Tags: php, html, formularios

Tengo el siguiente codigo pagina1.php

```
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case[]" value="<?php printf("%s",$row["nombre"]); printf("|"); printf("%s",$row["fecha"]); printf("|"); printf("%s",$row["hora"]);?>">
```

Lo mando a pagina2.php

```
$evento = $_POST["case"];

<form  id ="form3" action="pagina3.php" method="post" name="forma3">

    foreach ($evento as $value) {    
    printf("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"evento[]\" value=\"%s\" align=\"right\"/>",$value);
    }
</form>
```

El resultado si le doy un echo a `$value`
es el siguiente:

```
texto101.zip|2015-09-03|'04:00:00'
```

En la pagina3.php lo recibo asi

```
$evento = $_POST["evento"];
```

Como es posible almacenar cada valor a partir de `$evento` en variables y que quede algo asi:

```
name=texto101.zip
fecha=2015-09-03
hora='04:00:00'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La función `explode()` de PHP divide un string en varios strings a partir de un delimitador pasado por parámetro. Por lo que en pagina2.php podrías hacer:

```
$evento = $_POST["evento"];
list( $name, $fecha, $hora ) = explode( "|", $evento );
```

Luego tendrías en cada una de esas variables el contenido que estás buscando.

Comment: probe hacerlo de la manera en que comentas, y no hace nada. ademas, quiero que de la pagina2.php se pase a la pagina3.php

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @Lucas apunta a tomar lo que recibes en la pagina3.php, es decir:

```
$evento = $_POST["evento"];
list( $name, $fecha, $hora ) = explode("|", $evento );

echo "name: $name <br>";
echo "fecha: $fecha <br>";
echo "hora: $hora";
```

Lo que esta haciendo el **explode**, es separar tu string por el delimitador **|**

Posteriormente el **list**, lo que hace es guardar cada posicion que encontro en una variable, seria lo mismo que hacer:

```
$arreglo = explode( "|", $evento );
$name = arreglo[0];
$fecha = arreglo[1];
$hora = arreglo[2];
```

Entiendes?

Si quieres pasar las variables ya separadas de la pagina 2 a la 3, deberias pasarlas como un hidden oculto con cada valor, asumiendo que hiciste lo que esta arriba y se las pasaste a la vista o pagina2.

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="fecha" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="hora" value="<?php echo $hora; ?>" />
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = explode( "|", $evento );
```

aca separas el string con el delimitador |

```
$nombre = array[0];// obtnes los strings por sus indices
$fecha = array[1];
$hora = array[2];
```

Si necesitas guardar esos datos temporalmente tambien podes usar la variables

```
$_SESSION[info] = $array;
```